# How to change date format from MM DD YYYY to DD MM YYYY?

Tags: sql

In SQL in a column How can I change date format from MM DD YYYY to DD MM YYYY?

I expect to have a date column in a DD MM YYYY date format

Comment: If you have data in a column, and that column is specifically a "date" (or date/time) data-type, then there's no particular format in the way that data is stored.  The formatting - that is, the way the date appears to you - is really dependent on the client application that is being used to display the date.  Unless you're particularly wanting the results of a SELECT statement to output a date value formatted as DD/MM/YYYY - in which case, it might be an idea if you also tag your specific database server (eg. SQL Server, MySQL, etc.) as the method for that may vary slightly between RDBMS

Comment: Which Database you are using; Also;
Is there space in the above defined formats ?
`MM DD YYYY` and `DD MM YYYY`